# Easier way to update PHP 5.5 to 7.0 on an older version of XAMPP

Tags: php, heroku, composer-php

I'm using XAMPP for windows 5.5.37 and can't run this "composer update" command to install the required dependencies.

I was following this guide: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-php?singlepage=true#declare-app-dependencies and come across with some problems.

After running composer update:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - twig/twig v2.9.0 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.5.37) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - twig/twig v2.8.1 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.5.37) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - twig/twig v2.8.0 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.5.37) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - twig/twig v2.7.4 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.5.37) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - twig/twig v2.7.3 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.5.37) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - twig/twig v2.7.2 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.5.37) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - twig/twig v2.7.1 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.5.37) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - twig/twig v2.7.0 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.5.37) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - twig/twig v2.6.2 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.5.37) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - twig/twig v2.6.1 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.5.37) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - twig/twig v2.6.0 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.5.37) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - twig/twig v2.5.0 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.5.37) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - twig/twig v2.4.8 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.5.37) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - twig/twig v2.4.7 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.5.37) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - twig/twig v2.4.6 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.5.37) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - twig/twig v2.4.5 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.5.37) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - twig/twig v2.4.4 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.5.37) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - twig/twig v2.4.3 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.5.37) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - twig/twig v2.4.2 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.5.37) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - twig/twig v2.4.1 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.5.37) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - twig/twig v2.4.0 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.5.37) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - twig/twig v2.3.2 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.5.37) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - twig/twig v2.3.1 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.5.37) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - twig/twig v2.3.0 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.5.37) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - twig/twig v2.2.0 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.5.37) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - twig/twig v2.13.1 requires php >=7.1.3 -> your PHP version (5.5.37) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - twig/twig v2.13.0 requires php >=7.1.3 -> your PHP version (5.5.37) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - twig/twig v2.12.5 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.5.37) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - twig/twig v2.12.4 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.5.37) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - twig/twig v2.12.3 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.5.37) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - twig/twig v2.12.2 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.5.37) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - twig/twig v2.12.1 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.5.37) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - twig/twig v2.12.0 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.5.37) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - twig/twig v2.11.3 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.5.37) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - twig/twig v2.11.2 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.5.37) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - twig/twig v2.11.1 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.5.37) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - twig/twig v2.11.0 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.5.37) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - twig/twig v2.10.0 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.5.37) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - twig/twig v2.1.0 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.5.37) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - twig/twig v2.0.0 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.5.37) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Installation request for twig/twig ^2.0 -> satisfiable by twig/twig[v2.0.0, v2.1.0, v2.10.0, v2.11.0, v2.11.1, v2.11.2, v2.11.3, v2.12.0, v2.12.1, v2.12.2, v2.12.3, v2.12.4, v2.12.5, v2.13.0, v2.13.1, v2.2.0, v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.2, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.5.0, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.2, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.7.4, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.9.0].
```

How can I safely update my PHP version to 7.0 from 5.5?

Comment: [PHP 7.0 is beyond end of life](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php), you should upgrade to a version that is actually supported.

Comment: Also, if upgrading is still a problem, show what you've tried. Upgrading PHP on your local system is not related to Heroku or Composer, so please don't use unrelated tags